# Flink: submitting job failed to deserialize JobGraph

Tags: apache-flink

I was trying to submit a Flink job to a cluster:

```
./bin/flink run -m <ip>:8081  examples/batch/WordCount.jar --input /opt/flink/README.txt
```

but got the error `Failed to deserialize JobGraph`:

```
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Could not retrieve the execution result. (JobID: 6095949ee689e308039dbc62da2bdf03)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.submitJob(RestClusterClient.java:255)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:338)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:326)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ContextEnvironment.execute(ContextEnvironment.java:62)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.execute(ExecutionEnvironment.java:820)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet.collect(DataSet.java:413)
    at org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet.print(DataSet.java:1652)
    at org.apache.flink.examples.java.wordcount.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:576)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:438)
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:274)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:746)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.runProgram(CliFrontend.java:273)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:205)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1010)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1083)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:30)
    at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1083)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
    at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.lambda$submitJob$8(RestClusterClient.java:382)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:870)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:852)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1977)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$8(FutureUtils.java:263)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:561)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:929)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.util.RestClientException: [Failed to deserialize JobGraph.]
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient.parseResponse(RestClient.java:389)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient.lambda$submitRequest$3(RestClient.java:373)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniCompose(CompletableFuture.java:952)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:926)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out it is a compatibility issue, the cluster is Flink 1.8.1 while the CLI and job jar is from Flink 1.9.0. After switching to the same version, it worked.

Comment: getting the same error, org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the issue was happening because the Flink cluster was not started

./bin/start-cluster.sh

Answer (score 1):

In my case (when I was playing Flink + Beam) it was the issue with version compatibility.

I had some example Beam job which was running on GCP DataFlow but get the mentioned error on Flink 1.15.X + Beam 2.38.X.

When switched to Flink 1.14.X then job run successfully so be careful regarding dependencies.